# jquery date range validator not showing error message

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am using jquery daterange validator on my asp.net mvc page `http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/multiplefields`. my html looks like this:

```
 <tr>
            <td align="left" valign="top">
                <label>
                    <input name="fromDate" type="text" class="flat requiredDateRange jq_watermark" id="fromDate"
                        style="width: 190px" title="Creation From Date" readonly="readonly" />
                </label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="left" valign="top">
                <label>
                    <input name="toDate" type="text" class="flat requiredDateRange jq_watermark" id="toDate"
                        style="width: 190px" title="Creation To Date" readonly="readonly" />
                </label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" align="left" valign="top">
                <label id="error" class="error" style="display: block;">
                </label>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

where as at page top, I am using this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#fromDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd MM yy', changeYear: true, changeMonth: true });
        $("#toDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd MM yy', changeYear: true, changeMonth: true });
});
```

and

```
jQuery(function () {

    jQuery("#frmSearch").validate({
        groups: {
            datesnotnull: "fromDate toDate",
            dateRange: "fromDate toDate"
        },
        errorPlacement: function (error) {
            jQuery("#frmSearch").find("#error").append('error');
           jQuery("#frmSearch").find("#error").show();

        }
    });

});
```

my daterangevalidator file looks like this:

```
// a custom method for validating the date range
$.validator.addMethod("datesnotnull", function () {  
    return (($("#fromDate").val().length != 0) && ($("#toDate").val().length != 0)) || (($("#fromDate").val().length == 0) && ($("#toDate").val().length == 0));
}, "Please specify the date range, from and to date.");

// a custom method for validating the date range
$.validator.addMethod("dateRange", function () {


    return ((($("#fromDate").val().length==0) && ($("#toDate").val().length==0)) || (new Date($("#fromDate").val()) < new Date($("#toDate").val())));
}, "Please specify a correct date range, the from date must be before the to date.");


// a new class rule to group all three methods
$.validator.addClassRules({
    requiredDateRange: { required: false, date: true, datesnotnull : true , dateRange: true  }    
});

// overwrite default messages
$.extend($.validator.messages, {    
    date: "Please specify valid dates"
});
```

but when todate is less than from data, I get "Creation To Date" message only. I want to show message "Please specify a correct date range, the from date must be before the to date" which is default message in red color

Comment: Could you please post a fiddle?

Comment: @raghavv html is not plain, it is generated using asp.net mvc view and cant use fiddle

Comment: You still can use the generated html from asp and use it on jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following option within `validate()`:

```
ignoreTitle: true
```

Answer (score 0):

new Date($("#fromDate").val()) returns with a string. You should compare the millisec values instead: new Date($("#fromDate").val()).getTime()